# Recursively find same name files between two folders using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have two folders which have many sub folders like:

c:\bundles [bundles has apibundle, appbundle, etc.]
c:\web\css [css folder has css files like 123.css, 335.css]

I want to find path matching css files inside bundles folder for example:

```
c:\bundles\appbundle\123.css -> match -> c:\web\css\123.css
```

is this possible to do in powershell? can anyone give me example how this can be done.

By the way i am trying this but it is very time consuming adding each file name one by one:

```
gci -Path C:\bundles -recurse -filter "123.css"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to compare the file name you can use `Compare-Object` like this :

```
Compare-Object -Property name -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent (Get-ChildItem "C:\bundles" -recurse) (Get-ChildItem "c:\web\css" -recurse)
```